# Difference in String array declaration. String[] foo or String foo[]

Tags: java, android

What is the fundamental difference between declaring

```
String foo[];
```

and

```
String[] foo;
```

Ex: I am using a spinner and the first example works while the second example doesn't, even though I don't have any other problems in the rest of my code using the second declaration method.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    String[] Condicoes = {fase, comunicacao,tipo_comunicacao};
    String concat = "";
    for (int k = 0; k < Condicoes.length; k++) {
        String newfer[] = StringMapper.get(Condicoes[k]);

        for(int i = 0; i<newfer.length; i++) {
            //ArrayAdapter<String> spinningspinenER = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InsertID.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, newfer);

            concat += newfer[i];
            concat += "\n";
        }
    }
    textView.setText(concat);
}
```

This is the code that gives me an error if I use:

`String[] newfer = StringMapper.get(Condicoes[k]);`

in the commented part

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> spinningspinenER = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InsertID.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, newfer);
```

it says that it can not build the ArrayAdapter

Comment: add some exaple of what you do, what you exepect and what it's huppen.

Comment: There is no difference. It is the same see : https://stackoverflow.com//questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java

Comment: what problem you get?

Comment: the `[]` placement is not possible to be the root cause of the problem in the program, both declarations are fully legal in java code. Paste the stack trace you get on failure.

Comment: Well it seems my problem disappeared, it might have been a problem declaring the array at first. Because when i switched it around again it was fine, maybe a missing colon or something. Thanks to everyone anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are basically the same

```
String[] foo; //preferred way
```

or 
    String foo[];// works but not preferred way

String arrays are put in the following way

```
 String[] Condicoes = {"fase", "comunicacao","tipo_comunicacao"};
```

for array adapter I think this the one you are trying to use

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, int, T[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[]))